# Openapi-generator - format date + pattern

Tags: java, openapi-generator

I am using openapi generator and I am asking about date declaration with a pattern. I saw that this functionnality have to past by String field like this :

```
customDate: 
  type: string 
  pattern: '^\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$'
  description: Custom date 
  example: "20210130"
```

but is there any means to keep LocalDate field and have a custom pattern ?

Comment: How are you using `LocalDate` here? Can you show us your parsing code?

Comment: Yes we use LocalDate but we would like to have a different pattern.
Choose a format date generate this code 

 
`@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso = org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)`


(finally we choose the standard format but if there is a solution, it can maybe help someone).